# Is there a Java method for sorting points?

Tags: java, sorting, 2d, points

`java.awt.Point[] coordinates = new Main().findPlayers(photo, team, threshold);`

I have a function that returns an array of points (coordinates of players).
And I want to sort the players in increasing order by x-coordinate.
Then sort players with the same x-coordinate in increasing order by y-coordinate.
I sorted it in a naive way but it's not quite neat.

Answer (score 0):

No, that'd be far too specific; java is a general purpose programming language.

There is, however, a function to sort anything. You can use that to sort an array of points quite easily.

This function requires that you provide an 'ordering oracle': A bit of wisdom that answers the question: "Which one comes first", given any 2 thingies you want to sort. With just that oracle, java ships code that can then sort any array.

Java also ships with tools to make these oracles very simply, by mapping any 'thingie' to something that knows how to sort itself. Numbers and Strings know this. You can also specify 'add-on' sub-oracles that get used solely if the primary oracle cannot answer because they seem equal to it.

In action:

```
Arrays.sort(coordinates, 
  Comparator.comparingInt(Point::getX).thenComparingInt(Point::getY));
```

`Point::getX` is the *concept* of the getX method. It doesn't execute the method, it passes the method itself (not the return value of executing it). The `Comparator.comparingInt` method is a built-in that makes comparators when you provide it code that turns any 'thing you want to sort' into an int. Hence, you pass the concept of 'call the getX method on a Point, and voila, an int to sort on'. The `thenComparingInt` adds an add-on that is used solely to determine the 'winner' between 2 points with identical x coordinates.